# Is there a slick proof of the fundamental theorem of dimension theory?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, alternative-proof

The fundamental theorem of dimension theory in commutative algebra states that given a module $M$ over a noetherian local ring $A$, we have $s(M)=\text{dim}(M)=d(M)$ (where $s(M)$ is the infimum of integers $k$ such that there exists $x_1...x_k$ such that $M/(x_1...x_k)M$ is of finite length, and $d(M)$ is the degree of the Samuel polynomial of $M$)

I know about the standard proof as is written down in Serre's *Local Algebra*, or in the book *Homological Methods for Commutative Algebra* [S. Raghavan, R. Balwant Singh, R. Sridharan] 
(side question: what are other good references for the dim. theorem? Please add details).

**Question**

> I was wondering if there exists some slick / more conceptual proof by applying
>   some more technology, maybe using homological algebra or
>   algebraic geometric methods, or whatever.

Comment: Atiyah-MacDonald.

Comment: @WalterNeff Yes, you can call it the Hilbert-Samuel polynomial.

Comment: +1 for "I would like a proof slicker than Serre's".

Comment: @roysmith +1 for making me laugh :)